# How does windows OS determine to which window a message should be posted

Tags: windows, winapi

**Question:**

Let's say I have a process with a main window and a child window. When I type using my keyboard how does the operating system determine the HWND to send a WM_KEYDOWN message to?

I know about the event loop and the functions GetMessage, TranslateMessage and DispatchMessage, but I don't understand how the hwnd field is set in the MSG struct.

**Examples:**

Using Spy++ I see that sometimes the child window receives the WM_KEYDOWN message and sometimes the parent window.

In winforms a textbox that has focus receives the message. However in other UIs the message skips the child window and is posted straight to the main window.

Comment: It goes to the focus window.

Comment: As in [`GUITHREADINFO::hwndFcous`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-guithreadinfo). Also [Keyboard input model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input). A child window can reject a focus by catching `WM_SETFOCUS` and setting the focus to its parent.

Comment: "However in other UIs the message skips the child window and is posted straight to the main window." Could you give an example of this kind of UI?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT , this is a mainframe emulator. I don't know if I can mention the name of the UI, but basically it has a top-level window and a child which is the terminal itself, however the child doesn't receive the keyboard input, only the parent. I guess in this specific app only the top-level window has the keyboard focus and it handles the keyboard events.

Comment: Is your case described as @MSalters ?

Comment: I don't have access to the source code. But it might be the case. Is there a way I can check this out?
I do see that posting a WM_KEYDOWN to a child (from an external process) makes it send (not post) this message to the parent

Comment: @EtanGrundstein: `GetGUIThreadInfo` should work on other processes, too. If you explicitly send a `WM_KEYDOWN` to a child, it can programmatically re-send it to its parent. That's just a few lines of code. This forwarding can even be conditional depending on the key and other factors; Windows doesn't know anything about such logic. Windows just handles the first delivery to the focus HWND.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input is sent to the window which has focus

Per the comment from MSalters:

the [GITHREADINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-guithreadinfo) structure contains the variable:

```
HWND  hwndFocus;

Type: HWND

A handle to the window that has the keyboard focus.
```

This is the default behavior.  If a program is forwarding the message to another window, then that behavior was implemented by the developer.

There are many ways to detect and handle input, but the standard method would be to use the message queue.  You may find programs which detect input without having focus and it could be because they're using an alternative method of reading input, for example GetKeyboardState().

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems that GetGUIThreadInfo does the trick. However, when I run GetGUIThreadInfo from a different process, it will return the GUITHREADINFO structure with non-blank fields only if a window in the target process is activated. (I checked it with different apps, notepad is one of them).
Is there a way to get the structure filled with the no window activated?

Comment: @EtanGrundstein "If the specified thread does not exist or have an input queue, the function will fail." Maybe this means when window is not active/focus the input queue doesn't exist?  Not sure